# UIImage Caching cause memory high

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage

Consider:

```
+(nullable UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name;
```

I use this method like so:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
```

But my image's type is png.

[image]

In my project, loads a lot of different images.

So, My cache is very hight

[image]

Comment: When you use a 3001 x 4057 image, it doesn't matter what the original file size was, it will uncompress it, generally taking four bytes per pixel. Use images that are appropriately sized for the target devices, but not larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are huge. 3001*4057 is roughly 12 million pixels. Theres 3 bytes in one pixel (one byte for red, green and blue each), so an image with that size would have 12million * 3 bytes, which is about 36MB per image.

I would scale down your image size if you can.

Comment: Actually, that's generally four bytes per pixel, one for red, green, blue and alpha, respectively, so it's even worse.

Comment: Thank you very much.So,The reason is my image's pixel.I got it